# Validar Data entrada pelo EditText

Tags: android, validação, data

Tenho um EditText com Mask para entrada de uma data.
Como posso validar se a data existe ou não?

Código do meu EditText

```
NascimentoUsu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtdata_usu);
NascimentoUsu.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##/##/####", NascimentoUsu));
```

Comment: Você quer validar durante a digitação ou ao final?

Comment: Não pensei nisso qualquer uma das soluções seria bem vinda. Mais preferia no final quando mandar salvar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de validar seria usando um `SimpleDateFormat` e usando a flag de [`lenient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) da classe `DateFormat`. O padrão é `true`, para capturar erros de formatação deve usar ela como `false`.

Exemplificando:

```
// Configure o SimpleDateFormat no onCreate ou onCreateView
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

sdf.setLenient(false);

// Durante a confirmacao de cadastro, faça a validacao

String data = NascimentoUsu.getText().toString();

try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(data);
    // Data formatada corretamente
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Erro de parsing!!
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A flag `lenient` sendo `true`, faz com que o `SimpleDateFormat` use uma heurística para corrigir dados "errados".

Com `lenient true`, a data **29/02/2014** seria convertida para **01/03/2014**. Usando `lenient` como `false`, ele gera um erro de parsing.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, agora estou com outra dificuldade a partir de ter validado a data como posso verificar se a pessoa é maior de 18 anos?

Comment: Da uma olhada na solução dessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906301/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-years-between-two-dates-in-android, usando o `Calendar` da pra fazer essa conta.